# Rotação de ícone de 0 graus a 180 graus ao ser clicado (DOM)

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick, transform

Eu gostaria de uma sugestão, para que o ícone de "angle-down", fique alternando de 0 graus e 180 graus quando for clicado!

```html
<div class="container-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down" onclick="rotateAngleDown()"></i>
</div>
```

Estou utilizando esse código (DOM Javascript), porém quando clico o ícone altera para 180 graus, porém não retorna para 0 graus:

```js
function rotateAngleDown(){

    document.querySelector('.fa-angle-down').style.transform = 'rotate(180deg)';
    
}
```

Comment: Por pouco acertaria o código,só faltou uma variável que guarda o estado da `let estadoAtual = 0;function rotateAngleDown(){if(estadoAtual === 0){estadoAtual = 180; document.querySelector('.fa-angle-down').style.transform = 'rotate(180deg)';}else{estadoAtual = 0;document.querySelector('.fa-angle-down').style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)';}}`

Comment: acho que dessa forma, não !!!

Comment: Oi @stack.cardoso , boa noite! Cara, utilizei ser código aqui e está funcionando! Muito obrigado pela sugestão. Só tenho a agradecer! Abraços.

Comment: Oi @stack.cardoso, por favor, depois me passe o link para eu dar um "joínha" na sua resposta! muito obrigado!

Comment: @stack.cardoso  Olha 

Answer (score 1):

> Preze por separar código, estilo e visualização. Organização impõe uma
> aparência mais profissional ao seu trabalho facilitando a leitura e
> escrita de sua página, assim tornando mais fácil fazer sua manutenção.

Uma solução seria adicionar um seletor de classe CSS para fazer a rotação através da propriedade [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) configurada com a [função de transformação rotação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function).
Com o auxilio do método [`Element.classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) a cada evento clique remova ou adicione essa classe ao seu ícone.

Para um efeito mais dramático você usar uma [transição](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/transition).

```js
const icone = document.querySelector('.fa-angle-down');

icone.addEventListener("click", function() {
  icone.classList.toggle("updown");
});
```

```css
i {
  transition:.3s ease-in-out;
}

.updown {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Caso não seja interessante uma animação, pode ainda com `Element.classList.toggle()` alternar a classe do ícone entre `fa-angle-down` e `fa-angle-up`.

```js
const icon = document.querySelector('.fa-angle-down');

icon.addEventListener("click", function() {
  icon.classList.toggle("fa-angle-down");
  icon.classList.toggle("fa-angle-up");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Você pode utilizar a propriedade "classList" do elemento selecionado para adicionar e remover classes que contenham as regras de rotação desejadas.

Por exemplo, crie duas classes CSS, uma chamada "rotate-0" e outra chamada "rotate-180", e adicione as regras de rotação correspondentes a cada uma delas.

Em seguida, você pode utilizar a função "classList.toggle()" dentro da sua função "rotateAngleDown()" para alternar entre as classes "rotate-0" e "rotate-180" a cada clique no ícone:

```
    function rotateAngleDown(){
    var angleDown = document.querySelector('.fa-angle-down');
    angleDown.classList.toggle("rotate-0");
    angleDown.classList.toggle("rotate-180");
}
```

Isso permitirá que o ícone altere sua rotação entre 0 e 180 graus a cada clique.

Lembrando que é necessário criar as classes ".rotate-0" e ".rotate-180" no seu arquivo css.